# Require login before populating jTable with Oracle DB values

Tags: java, database, oracle, netbeans, jtable

I have a jTable populated with values from an Oracle DataBase.
To make this connection I had to give the connection name and password in the NetBeans popup [(this one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wsKi.png), but I would like to this in a form (a login window).

Where could I change the values from the NetBeans properties in my code? (I really don't know where to look for it as I've not found any example of something similar)

Comment: `is this possible?` yes. `Where could I change this?` - in your code.

Comment: Yeah i know that @camickr, but where? I've been searching for it but couldn't find it..

Comment: What to you mean where? We don't know how your code is structured. You would do it at the start of your class. I would guess the first thing you do is display a JDialog to prompt for the userid and password. When valid you display your main frame.

Comment: Yes I have the dialog to ask for the password.
I have used the Table Content prompt to create the connection, and i can't find any place in my code where I might "change" that connection

Comment: Probably somewhere in your code, it's a section regarding database connection, JDBC url. There the value from the JDialog should go. How can  we imagine how does your code looks? You did not shared any code.